# How to make an animation shadowOffset in Swift?

Tags: swift, cabasicanimation

I wrote the code but I can not understand why it does not work...

```
func animate(vc: UIView) {
    vc.layer.shadowColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9254902005, green: 0.2352941185, blue: 0.1019607857, alpha: 1)
    vc.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    vc.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    let animationX = CABasicAnimation()
    animationX.keyPath = "shadowOffset"
    animationX.fromValue = vc.layer.shadowOffset
    animationX.toValue = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
    animationX.duration = 1
    vc.layer.add(animationX, forKey: animationX.keyPath)
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
  animate(vc: sender)
}
```

Does anyone know how this works?

Comment: What's the question? It seems to be about what "anyone knows", which is improbable. Is it that you want to animate the shadow offset?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things missing

1. shadowPath
2. shadowOpacity

```
        vc.layer.masksToBounds = false
        vc.layer.shadowColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9254902005, green: 0.2352941185, blue: 0.1019607857, alpha: 1)
        vc.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        vc.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        vc.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: vc.bounds).cgPath
        vc.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        let animationX = CABasicAnimation()
        animationX.keyPath = "shadowOffset"
        animationX.fromValue = vc.layer.shadowOffset
        animationX.toValue = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
        animationX.duration = 1
        vc.layer.add(animationX, forKey: animationX.keyPath)
```

By default `shadowOpacity` is 0.

**Final O/P**

[image]

**EDIT:**

If you want shadow to persist in its position even after animation specify

1. fillMode
2. isRemovedOnCompletion

final code will look like

```
func animate(vc: UIView) {
        vc.layer.masksToBounds = false
        vc.layer.shadowColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9254902005, green: 0.2352941185, blue: 0.1019607857, alpha: 1)
        vc.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        vc.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        vc.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: vc.bounds).cgPath
        vc.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        let animationX = CABasicAnimation()
        animationX.keyPath = "shadowOffset"
        animationX.fromValue = vc.layer.shadowOffset
        animationX.toValue = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
        animationX.duration = 1
        animationX.fillMode = .forwards
        animationX.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        vc.layer.add(animationX, forKey: animationX.keyPath)
    }
```

**Final O/P looks like:**

[image]

Comment: Sandeep Bhandari Thank you very much now I understand how it works

Comment: @nikolay-nikolaenko: Please accept my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Hello @SandeepBhandari, could you help me with the same problem but using the shadowPath? I would need to animate a UIView vertical growing with its shadow border: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65492182/how-to-animate-the-shadow-border-of-an-uiview-at-the-same-time-its-content-grows